# How does an app keep track of connections to other computers?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I was thinking about the concept of a software port which helps distinguish which internet packets belong to which application and i was wondering what similar construct does an app itself use to distinguish between two different connections that it might be attempting. For example, if an app X with asynchronous execution has initiated a connection on line 10 in its source code and then it starts another one on line 11 while the first connection is still ongoing what does it use to keep track of these connections?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that depending on the connection type, there must be an identifier for it.

Take for example socket connections, assuming a client is using [*socket.io*](https://socket.io/) for initiating multiple connections with other processes, for every connection there is a unique id for it.

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(socket.id); // 'G5p5...'
});
```

This might be a little abstracted, but even on the low level, the same thing happens.